# Solution for user data storage on Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: kubernetes, filesystems, storage, nfs

I'm developing a SaaS solution on GCP, service mainly running GKE. Service will provide each user with a private space on disk (folder to keep their files and folder).

Technical requirements:

- Mount with ReadWriteMany to multiple pods
- The number of users: around a few hundred thousand.
- Each user's private storage size will be pretty small around a few hundred MB each up to a few GB max. But the number of files will be pretty huge, ~ few thousands to hundred thousand
- File access will be mostly small reads and writes.
- There will be symbolic links to a shared system folder, but no symbolic link between users' folders.

I currently implement an NFS solution based on [this](https://github.com/kubernetes-retired/external-storage/tree/master/nfs), which is a pain to manage and the project is no longer maintained. I have to manually increase the size of backing PVC and restart all the pods that the PV is mounted in case I need to expand the storage capacity.

Filestore seems to be a very good alternative, but the cost is a big problem as it only allows minimum 1TB storage to be provisioned.

I'm looking for a solution that is easy to manage, good-enough performance and cost-effective. Any recommendation is appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I read that you specified that you have tried GlusterFS but have you read this article about setup with Heketi https://medium.com/searce/glusterfs-dynamic-provisioning-using-heketi-as-external-storage-with-gke-bd9af17434e5 ?

Comment: @MaggieO i did take a look into it, the fact that the maintainer placing it into bug-fixes-only mode is a dealbreaker for me, i want to use something that is actively developed and maintain

Comment: Did you manage to find appropriate tool for you ?

Comment: @Malgorzata After studying a number of technologies, I decided to go with  [Rook NFS](https://rook.io/docs/rook/v1.4/nfs-crd.html) . It is flexible enough for my use case and looks like will become standard for K8S in the future (hosted under Cloud Native Computing Foundation). Rook Ceph is also promising but it looks like it only supports dynamically provision PD, I need to reuse existing PD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify what your end goal is but some alternatives:

- [A set of more recent YAML files](https://github.com/mappedinn/kubernetes-nfs-volume-on-gke)
- [Rook](https://rook.io/) (CSI)
- [Ceph](https://ceph.io/)
- [Glusterfs](https://www.gluster.org/)
- [OpenEBS](https://openebs.io/)
- [Kubernetes support for gce volume resizing](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/12/resizing-persistent-volumes-using-kubernetes/).

Some of the solutions above will still involve restarting the pods.

✌️

Comment: I did try Ceph and GlusterFS but they are so hard to set up. There seems to be no thorough guide to set up these technologies on K8S. It would be great if you can point me to some very specific guide to get it working on GKE.  
Rook and OpenEBS seem very promising, I will take a look.